# “Can't determine type for tag” on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Might be a syntax error but I'm struggling to find it

> Can't determine type for tag '<TextView android:background="#E339" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/helloText" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:textSize="40sp" tools:text="hello"/>'

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/helloText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#E339"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="hello"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Try using a six- or eight-digit hex color for `android:background`.